# Interacting with rad grid? How to declare the custom columns?

Tags: asp.net

In web application[asp.net], i am using telerik grid control, i am bind the data to grid when it is autocompletecolumns=true, now  i want to bind the data autogeneratecolumns=false how can i place controls like in asp.net grid we use

```
<columns><asp:Templatefileds><ItemTemplate><asp:label id ="lblid" runat="Server" 
  Text='<%# Eval("Empid") #> /></ItemTemplage></asp:templae>
```

Comment: Have you actually taken the time to look at the examples. They have lots and they are very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radgrid also have template column like ASP gridview, you can use template columns as:

```
<MasterTableView ShowFooter="False">

<Columns>

<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateColumn" SortExpression="CompanyName">

<ItemTemplate>
// Your Logic Here
</ItemTemplate>

</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

</Columns>
</MasterTableView>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When the columns are not autocompleted, you must specify them as tags inside your Columns tag. You must specify the attributes for the tags which denote your columns and in the NeedDatasource event you fill your datasource.